# Set different formatoptions for specific filetype

Tags: vim

I'm trying to turn on the `c` flag in formatoptions for all files except filetype vim. The following doesn't accomplish that:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNew,BufEnter *.* set      formatoptions+=c
autocmd FileType vim                setlocal formatoptions-=c
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing looks like that:

```
if foo == 1
    do something
elseif bar == "baz"
    do something else
```

One case is triggered by something and the other by something totally different so… the cases are not mutually exclusive.

Either you check for the same thing, like `FileType`, *or* you set a default value followed by a local value

```
set formatoptions+=c
autocmd FileType vim setlocal formatoptions-=c
```

With this, you have `c` for every filetype except `vim`.

Answer (score 2):

`FileType` event was triggered when the 'filetype' was set.

the `BufEnter *.*` will be triggered when you enter that buffer, that is,  it happened after `FileType` event, and added `c` again.

You could just in vimrc `set formatoptions+=c` and use only one autocmd, if vim filetype, remove the c from the option.